# why input and button is not side by side?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add the button next to the input box.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="imageidVal" class="col-md-1 control-label pull-left text-nowrap">Image Id:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageidVal" name="imageidVal" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Image Id" value='<jsp:getProperty property="imageID" name="adminObj"/>'>
                                </div>

                                <label for="cntridVal" class="col-md-1 control-label pull-left text-nowrap">Center Id:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cntridVal" name="cntridVal" placeholder="Center Id" value='<jsp:getProperty property="cntr_id" name="adminObj"/>'>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id = "searchCntrBtn" name="searchCntrBtn" onclick="getCntrDetails()">...</button> 

    </div>                   
</div>
```

Comment: I'd fix your formatting - this cut and paste snippet you have is quite hard to read. I'd try moving the `form-group` up to a parent div and just having the `row` class by itself and see how far that gets you, like they've got in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes under column sizing.

Comment: no ..after removed the <form-group> also not working. giving the same display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.form-control` forces an item to take up 100% of the available width.  You are using this on both the `<input>` and button.  You're going to have to re-format your code to address the issue... either by creating another `.col` for the button, or by making use of Bootstrap's Input Group component:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="imageidVal" class="col-xs-2 control-label pull-left text-nowrap">Image Id:</label>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageidVal" name="imageidVal" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Image Id" value='<jsp:getProperty property="imageID" name="adminObj"/>'>
 </div>

 <label for="cntridVal" class="col-xs-2 control-label pull-left text-nowrap">Center Id:</label>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cntridVal" name="cntridVal" placeholder="Center Id" value='<jsp:getProperty property="cntr_id" name="adminObj"/>'>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id = "searchCntrBtn" name="searchCntrBtn" onclick="getCntrDetails()">...</button> 
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>                   
</div>
```